# Can I run IOS app built by ionic2 for a simulation on Windows?

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic2

**Are there any ways to simulate ionic hybrid apps on Windows 7 without using MacOS or virtual machine such as VMware/virtual box?**.

Specifically, I read ionic documents and references and tried to apply **sim-ios & sim-deploy** on Windows 7. However, on Windows, sim-deploy seems **not supported**.
and the information I am looking for related to this is pretty much out-dated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

NO..., To simulate a app you need Xcode installed which you cannot on windows, You can get away with browser testing using Chrome built in browsers but that's about it.
I had the same issue when I wanted to Deploy a IOS app on windows

Comment: Ah~ OK. Thx. it helped